# Can't summon mossy stone bricks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using Minecraft 1.11 and am having trouble summoning a mossy stone brick. I am using /setblock and can summon a normal stone block, but not mossy. I have tried `mossy_stoneblock`, `stoneblock:1`, `stoneblock1` and much more. It just won't happen for me.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`/setblock` syntax:

```
/setblock X Y Z <block ID> [metadata] [oldBlockHandling] {NBT}
```

You must separate the block ID and metadata value. The correct ID is `minecraft:stonebrick` with a metadata value of 1:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:stonebrick 1
```

You can find a list of all block IDs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Block_IDs).

Answer (score -1):

In 1.13 and later versions, there is no concept of "block ID" and "Metadata value" and everything just has its own name:

```
/setblock <coords> mossy_stone_bricks
```

Comment: The question asks about Minecraft 1.11.

Comment: This answer is supposed to be addressed to future readers from 2023, not to the asker. This is what distinguishes the Stack Exchange network from a forum.